# Android with Webview overlapping top menu

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, webview

I am developing a android application, which contains a webview, and that webview runs google maps V3 in full screen, i notice that after some time of use and totally random. A "square" of the map overlaps the top of the Activity and even the top bar and i have no clue why.

In the image bellow i have an example.

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWJRu.png)

The layout is as simple as this. ive notice this more in tablets with 5.0.2, but because those are the ones most in test. With 4.4.2 i dont see it that much

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.cgi.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wview_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show your layout

Comment: post .xml code.